# Bitcoin symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How do I write the Bitcoin symbol in LaTeX?

- Abusing Unicode, "B⃦" can be used in normal text files. I'm not a fan of writing non-ASCII in LaTeX, as you can run into all sorts of encoding issues.
- There does not seem to be a package defining it.
- I could use TikZ to roll my own version, but then that would probably not scale well (telling from past attempts at similar things).

So: what do you think would be the best way of writing the Bitcoin currency symbol in LaTeX?

[For comparison, here's the Bitcoin wiki entry for the symbol.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201597

Comment: This is -- or should be -- 'Latin Capital Letter B with Stroke' (U+0243) (see [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/0243/)). So use a [font that has it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0243/fontsupport.htm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Three examples, from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.text.tex/aaDphoWpbwQ):

```
\def\bitcoinA{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip %\bfseries
    \setbox0=\hbox{B}%
    \setbox2=\hbox to\wd0{\hfil\hskip-.03em
    \vrule height .3ex width .15ex\hskip .08em
    \vrule height .3ex width .15ex\hfil}
    \vbox{\copy2\box0}\box2}}
```

and

```
\def\bitcoinB{\leavevmode
  {\setbox0=\hbox{\textsf{B}}%
    \dimen0\ht0 \advance\dimen0 0.2ex
    \ooalign{\hfil \box0\hfil\cr
      \hfil\vrule height \dimen0 depth.2ex\hfil\cr
    }%
  }%
}
```

and

```
\def\bitcoinC{\leavevmode\rlap{\hskip.5pt-}B}
```

[image]

Comment: As for now, only the last symbol posted by [Papiro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/bitcoin-symbol-in-latex#answer-112165) has to be used ([here's the why](http://bitcoinsymbol.org/)) Since this thread is still in use, I'll (picky me) slightly modify Papiro's answer by lowering the overlaid line to a more proper position : \def\btc{\leavevmode\rlap{\raisebox{-.7pt}{-}}B}

Comment: @Warren I think that advice is out-dated; as the [page linked by the OP](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol) says, Unicode has added [U+20BF](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=20BF) as the Bitcoin symbol in Unicode 10.0 released mid-2017, and already many fonts have support for it (₿). In the fonts and in the reference image, it looks closer to the first one above.

Answer (score 6):

A variant, more inline with the “official” rendering (see http://bitcoinsymbol.org)

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bitcoin}{{%
  \normalfont\sffamily
   \raisebox{-.05ex}{\makebox[.1\width][l]{-\kern-.2em-}}B%
}}

\begin{document}

\bitcoin

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the adjustments depend on the document sans serif font.

From the site:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the bitcoin symbol. Here is an attempt at drawing the Litecoin symbol in latex

```
\newcommand{\diaCo}{\mkern-\medmuskip\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\scalebox{0.9}{$-$}}\mkern-\medmuskip}%   
\def\litecoin{\leavevmode\rlap{\hskip-1.3pt \textbf{$\diaCo$}}L}
```

[image]