# How to create a "Bitcoin accepted here" button?

Tags: graphics

`\bitcoinacceptedhere`

Is there something like what appears above that causes a logo [like this](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/e/ed/Bitcoin_accepted_here_printable.png)

[image]

to appear in a document?

**Postscript:**  I've tried some of the things suggested in the several answers.  The one from Mark Wibrow results in error messages that I haven't figured out how to fix.  I've tried a few variants without success.

The answer from Kerren looks somewhat promising, since I can adjust the size and position.  However, I am now realizing I'd like to be able to use this in an inline setting.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what about using the image directly with `\includegraphic`?

Comment: @Guido : I didn't say "this logo"; I said "a logo like this".  I.e. I may want to edit it somewhat.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Use [Mark's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201618/5764) that should create a stand-alone PDF as output. Then you can include it in your document using `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 26):

Abandoning most of my previous answers to this question (see the edit history otherwise some of the comments below will make no sense) and combining the suggestion of percusse for the Ubuntu font and LaRiFaRi for fontawesome, I think this gets pretty close to the requirements (without actually using `\includegraphics`).

This needs to be compiled with `lualatex` or `xelatex` as it uses the `fontspec` package. In addition the `Ubuntu` font and latest version of the `fontawesome` font are required. For `fontawesome` I just deleted the existing version of `fontawesome.otf` in TeX-live and replaced it with the new version. There may be other ways of doing this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\bitcoin{\FA\symbol{"F15A}}
\setsansfont{Ubuntu} 
\colorlet{bitcoin}{orange!90!white}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
\draw [line width=.1ex, rounded corners=1ex, draw=gray!50,  top color=white, bottom color=gray!40] (-6,-2.25) rectangle (6,2.25);
\foreach \i in {0,100}{
  \node [circle, fill=bitcoin!\i, rotate=-15, inner sep=0.25ex, scale=0.625, text=white] 
    (symbol) at (-4,.25+\i/1500) {\bitcoin};
  \node [font=\sffamily\bfseries, xslant=0.25, text=black!80!white!\i,
right=0ex of symbol.south east, anchor=base west, inner ysep=0.25ex, inner xsep=0.5ex] 
    (bitcoin) {bitcoin};
  \node [font=\sffamily, xslant=0.25, scale=0.3, text=black!80!white!\i, anchor=north east, inner ysep=0ex, inner xsep=2ex] 
    at (bitcoin.south east) {ACCEPTED HERE};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great example of how to define a symbol respecting font sizes! Why do you set `\fboxsep`? Typo from tests?

Comment: @Bordaigorl if the `\fboxsep` is zero there is still a visible white border between the upper and lower edges of the "B" and the vertical bars (this may be a PDF viewer artifact but it still annoyed me). Setting it to slightly negative removed this white line,

Comment: Also there is something a bit wrong with the definition of the bitcoin symbol because if one follows directly after the other then there is overlapping.

Comment: The font is Ubuntu Bold Italic for the text. I coulnd't find the slab-serf B to tweak the bottom serif though.

Comment: This looks good, but I suppose I should have anticipated that what happened when I tried to run it is what usually happens when I ask about something a bit off the narrow path I've stuck to when using LaTeX: I got error messages that I don't know what to do with.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.

l.4 \usetikzlibrary

                   {positioning}

Comment: Can't help but be surprised by the beautiful things you do.

Comment: @MichaelHardy unless you have a super-old version of tikz then there should be no problem with the `positioning` library. You also need to compile with with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: @MarkWibrow : For starters, I never heard of lualatex or xelatex before posting this question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I guess the `\includegraphics` suggested by Kerren is probably the simplest way for you to go rather than fooling around with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. Try the documentation for the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 8):

**Second Update**:

I downloaded the [latest version of the font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and managed to get this symbol in place. In combination with normal text, it is quite thick. But in the symbol pilfered from Mark Wibrow, it looks quite nice.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\faBtc{\FA\symbol{"F15A}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\bitcoin}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,100}{
    \node [circle, fill=orange!90!white!\i, font=\large, inner sep=0.25ex, rotate=-15, text=white] 
    (symbol) at (-1.25,1/8+\i/4000) {\faBtc};}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\btc}{\ifmmode\text{\faBtc}\else\faBtc\fi}

\begin{document}
\SI{1000000}{\btc}
\bitcoin
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

For the general question on the symbol which should be used for bitcoins, I found [this homepage](http://bitcoinsymbol.org/). They suggest to give the bitcoins a symbol which is already available. They recommend the use of [the unicode U+0243](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0243/index.htm). I therefore do another MWE which is showing this symbol and its use with `siunitx`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\btc}{\ifmmode\text{\symbol{"0243}}\else\symbol{"0243}\fi}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}
    \symbol{"0243}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \symbol{"0243}
    \setmainfont{EBGaramond}
    \symbol{"0243}

    \SI{1000000}{\btc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

No there isn't. You will have to do this by your self with e.g. TikZ or you have to include the image itself, if the source is free (see Guidos comment).

The bitcoin letter itself is not yet in the unicode and therefore a bit hard to obtain. The font awesome already does have [a symbol](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/btc/) for this. I tested, but it is not yet included in the package `fontawesome`. You could ask the maintainer to insert it.

Finally, here is a nice bitcoin symbol in TikZ for you. It should be easy to rotate it a bit, change the colour and surround it by an orange circle.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.4pt, x=0.4pt,yscale=-1]
\path[fill=black] (214.9554,35.3243) -- (214.9554,171.6367) --
(77.1429,171.6367) -- (77.1429,191.4180) .. controls (164.6428,196.6263) and
(177.1429,208.0847) .. (177.1429,285.1680) -- (177.1429,747.6680) .. controls
(177.1429,824.7513) and (163.6011,838.2930) .. (77.1429,841.4180) --
(77.1429,861.1993) -- (214.9554,861.1993) -- (214.9554,1006.5430) --
(283.3616,1006.5430) -- (283.3616,861.1993) -- (344.0491,861.1993) --
(344.0491,1006.5430) -- (412.4554,1006.5430) -- (412.4554,861.1993) --
(425.0491,861.1993) .. controls (627.1322,861.1993) and (677.1429,748.6992) ..
(677.1429,673.6993) .. controls (677.1429,538.2827) and (540.6845,509.1159) ..
(499.0179,498.6993) .. controls (535.4761,489.3243) and (641.7054,468.4908) ..
(641.7054,348.6993) .. controls (641.7054,241.8602) and (563.9504,182.2120) ..
(412.4554,172.9180) -- (412.4554,35.3243) -- (344.0491,35.3243) --
(344.0491,171.6368) -- (283.3616,171.6368) -- (283.3616,35.3243) --
(214.9554,35.3243) -- cycle(306.2991,210.1680) -- (352.1429,210.1680) ..
controls (471.9344,210.1680) and (535.4554,260.1785) .. (535.4554,352.8868) ..
controls (535.4554,434.1367) and (480.2469,479.9493) .. (382.3304,479.9493) --
(283.3929,479.9493) -- (283.3929,241.4180) .. controls (283.3929,219.5430) and
(290.6741,210.1680) .. (306.2991,210.1680) -- cycle(283.3929,521.6368) ..
controls (421.9344,521.6368) and (557.3304,527.8869) .. (557.3304,674.7618) ..
controls (557.3304,797.6783) and (462.5594,822.6680) .. (349.0179,822.6680) ..
controls (297.9763,822.6680) and (283.3929,813.2826) .. (283.3929,779.9493) --
(283.3929,521.6368) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Out of curiostiy: did you take a svg version of fa and got the path from there?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I found the svg somewhere else and exported it via inkscape2tikz.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want the bitcoin symbol, here's a way

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bitcoin@add}{%
  \rule{.08em}{.08em}%
  \hspace{.08em}%
  \rule{.08em}{.08em}%
}
\newcommand{\bitcoin@skip}[1]{\hskip 0pt plus #1fil}
\newcommand{\bitcoin}{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{\bitcoin@skip{2}##\bitcoin@skip{3}\cr
      \vbox{\halign{\bitcoin@skip{2}##\bitcoin@skip{3}\cr\bitcoin@add\cr B\cr}}\cr
      \bitcoin@add\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
B\bitcoin B

{\small B\bitcoin B}

{\LARGE B\bitcoin B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another method you can use if it's an image could be this:

In your preamble (ie before `\begin{document}`) you can add:

```
\newcommand{\bitcoinacceptedhere}{
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{BitcoinAcceptedHerePrintable.png}
    \end{center}
\end{figure} }
```

Or if you don't want it to be that big you can do something like:

```
\newcommand{\bitcoinacceptedhere}{
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{BitcoinAcceptedHerePrintable.png}
    \end{center}
\end{figure} }
```

Where you change the scale factor. In both of these instances you'd just use 
`\bitcoinacceptedhere` in your code to place it.

Alternatively, if you'd like scale to be a parameter you could use:

```
\newcommand{\bitcoinacceptedhere}[1]{
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=#1]{BitcoinAcceptedHerePrintable.png}
    \end{center}
\end{figure} }
```

In this case you'd use `\bitcoinacceptedhere{0.3}` and you can change the factor to whatever you'd like :)

NOTE: Just make sure that the image is named without the "_" characters, that can mess up your compilation in some cases :)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! BTW, `\includegraphics` do not need a `figure` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always answer with at least one full example (compilable). You should not use `\begin{center}\end{center}` here, but `\centering`. I believe, the `[ht!]` is not necessary here. In fact, the whole floating environment can be left away.